# Normality and Conformal Mappings

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following question:

Show that there exists $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset A(\mathbb{D})$ such that each $f_n$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ conformally onto $\mathbb{D}$ and $f_n\rightarrow 1$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$.

I am trying to apply the definition of normality, but I'm just not sure how to find such an $f_n$

Def: A set $F\subset A(\Omega)$ is normal if and only if every sequence in $F$ contains a subsequence converging uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$.

Comment: I’m sorry, I can’t understand your reasoning. You seem to start from a given $(f_n)$, but you actually have to show its existence?

Comment: I modified the question.  Sorry about that, I had been thinking about the question for so long that it created a circular argument in my head :)

Comment: Hint: what conformal mappings of the disk onto itself do you know?

Comment: I know $\omega=\frac{z-a}{\bar{a}z-1}$ with |a|<1 maps the unit disk to itself.

Comment: Very good. Now can you find a sequence $a_n$ such that the mappings converge uniformly to $1$ in compacts?

Comment: I am struggling with this part.   Do you see it being worth playing a game with $n$ even and $n$ odd, or writing the sequence for $a_n$ in terms of $z$ maybe?

Comment: How about finding a value of $a$ (obviously $|a| \geq 1$) such that $f_a(z)=1$, and then approximate $a$ with values in the open unit disk?

Comment: Okay... well, if $a=1$, then we would get $f_a(z)=1$, right?  So, if I need to converge to $a=1$ from within the unit disk, could I do $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: That’s exactly it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patience; I can't tell you how much I appreciate it!

Comment: @Mindlack I have a quick question about something you said earlier about "in compacts". I suppose I'm just not sure what that means.  I know we have uniform convergence, but if we take out the "in compacts" part, why would the solution fail?   Thank you!

Comment: If the convergence were uniform (instead of merely uniform on compacts), then there would exist a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $z \in D$, $|f_n(z)-1| ? 1/2$, thus preventing $f_n$ from being onto.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.   Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that there exists $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that each $f_n$
maps $\mathbb{D}$ conformally onto $\mathbb{D}$ and $f_n\to 1$ uniformly on $\{|z|\le r\}$ for arbitrary fixed $r<1$.

Let $a_n=-1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $$f_n(z)=\frac{z-a_n}{1-a_nz}.$$ 
Then on $\{|z|\le r\}$, we have \begin{align}
|1-f_n(z)|&=\left|\frac{(1-z)(1+a_n)}{1-a_nz}\right|\le\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1+r}{1-r}\\
&\to 0
\end{align}
uniformly as $n\to\infty$.